# Converting XLSB to XLSX without using Microsoft.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, xlsb

As mention in title, is there any other ways I can use to convert XLSB to XLSX without using Microsoft.Interop.Excel?

I have check ExcelDataReader, EPPlus, CSharpJExcel, and NPOI and it does not support XLSB.

Comment: I have same problem, did you find any non-paid solution without Excel or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 dependency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com) is a library that supports both xlsb and xlsx files.

The below code is what you need for conversion:

```
ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument();
workbook.easy_LoadXLSBFile("Excel.xlsb");
workbook.easy_WriteXLSXFile("Excel.xlsx");
```

Comment: Is there any other aside from EasyXLS? It gives free access up to 30 days only.

Comment: Aspose.Cells...also trial

Comment: is there any non-trial tool? Spire.doc is other trial tool at Nuget. I think  NPOI supports reading and writing of all types of files. In my opinion  you need to try with "XLSX" MIME type when writing the file after reading and manipulating "xlsb" file.

Comment: I know that NPOI does not support xlsb files. xlsx and xlsb are different formats. But if it does, I would like to know.